# Mysql limiting one table column results allowing other column to display full data

Tags: mysql

I have following problem I want to display MySQL query in following way:
[image]

However I am getting following;

[image]

So far I was trying group by clause and according to post I did found on the forum the close one to achieve this what I want required use of Distinct which I was trying to implement in to my code. Also I did try left join.
My question is it is possible to achieve required formatting and if yes how can it be done.

My sql looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (shield.shieldDate),shield.shieldTeam, shieldMatch.score, players.firstname, players.lastname
FROM  `shieldMatch` 
JOIN shield ON shield.shieldID = shieldMatch.fk_shieldID
JOIN players ON shieldMatch.fk_playerID = players.playerID
WHERE shieldID =1
```

My tables have following:
table players:

```
playerID
firstname
lastname
```

table shield:

```
shieldID
shieldDate
shieldTeam
```

table shieldMatch:

```
shieldMatchID
fk_playerID
fk_shieldID
score
```

Please help thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Issues of data display are typically resolved in the presentation layer/application-level code.

Comment: I was thinking it would be easier to sort it now so it would be easier to display data later on in presentation layer and with current exampl I am restricting results to one Id what if I will have a lot of results to display in one go

Comment: Quite the opposite. Much easier to handle display in presentation layer.

Comment: Can you show me an example based on my question how I can extract that query  in php to achieve the required result please?

Comment: No. That would be silly. There must be a billion examples of this out there. Also, please note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this you can do it

```
<?php
    // execute and fetch your query result
    $result = ....
    $sdate = '';
    $outhtml = '<table><tr><td>Col 1></td><td>Col 3</td><td>col 4</td></tr>';
    foreach($result as $row){
      if($row['shieldDate'] != $sdate){
         $sdate = $row['shieldDate'];
         $outhtml .= '<tr><td>'.$row['shieldDate'].'</td><td>'.$row['shieldTeam'].'</td><td>'.$row['score'].'</td><td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
       }eles{
          $outhtml .= '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'..$row['score'].'</td><td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
       }
    }
    echo $outhtml;
```

Comment: thanks for help that was very useful!!!, it would be nice to know how to achieve this in MySQL just out of curiosity.